# Jquery Place item dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a way to place element just next to the item.

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/6zj1s18s/1/) . I am setting button item dynamically like this

```
var button_text = "Learn Now";
$("#ctaBtn").text(button_text);
$("#ctaBtn").css('width', parseFloat(textWidth(button_text) + 30) + "px");
```

Which is fine but i want the logo which is next to the button adjust its position dynamically. If i change my button text to

```
var button_text = "Learn More Now !!!";
```

Then the size of the button increases and logo position is not moved to the right. How can i move the logo dynamically based on the button text size?

Comment: How about using `$.css` and change the `left` property ? I don't see your button text change at all..

Comment: yup i am thinking the same but i am not able to find out exact positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the left position from the `#Image_logo img` and set a right position instead with jQuery. Something like this:

```
$("#Image_logo img").css("right", $("#ctaBtn").width() + 60);
```

Instead of 60 you can use any value that is better for you. Now, when you dynamically change the text in the button, the logo moves to the left with it.

Check the code on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zj1s18s/2/).